# Android REST API using PATCH method

Tags: android, api, rest

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(strUrl);

        StringEntity params =new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8");
        //request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        params.setContentType("application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity entity1 = response.getEntity();
        is = entity1.getContent();
        int resopnceStatus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "get data resopnceStatus: " + resopnceStatus);

        if (resopnceStatus != 200) {
            return "Invalid";
        }
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException timeout) {
        timeout.printStackTrace();
        return "Invalid";
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException timeout) {
        timeout.printStackTrace();
        return "Invalid";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Invalid";
    }

    String response = "";
    String s = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            response += s;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "get data Error in Buffered: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    AppLog.logString(TAG + "get data Return Data is: " + response);
```

Using above code in normal post rest web service it's working fine but in PATCH api its not working giving responce status 400 meance page not found but it's working fine in Chrome rest client.
Any solution for PATCH?

Comment: can you share more details on `in PATCH api its not working`

Comment: @nikis what ?? it's giving me error in android while in Chrome rest client working fine

Comment: wonderful. you are talking about error without posting it.

Comment: @nikis it's giving responce code 400 meance page not found but exactly this is not right way to call PATCH method but i dont know

Comment: code `400` doesn't mean that page is not found, it means that request is bad. You can start from comparison of requests you send from `Android` and `Chrome`.

Comment: i had comparision both thing i m posting via post but i cannot found any PATCH method in DefaultClient().

Comment: yes, there is no `HttpPatch` in android sdk (however, it exists in full `Apache HttpClient` http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPatch.html). Instead of adding whole `Apache HttpClient` as dependency you can write your own implementation of `HttpPatch` as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207373/http-patch-request-from-android

Comment: @nikis for thisn i need to add any external jar fiel?

Comment: no, just write your own implementation of `HttpPatch` as shown in the second link

Answer (score 0):

Download httpclient-4.2.jar file.

import below files

`import org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPatch;`

Put

`HttpPatch request = new HttpPatch(strUrl);`

Insted of

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(strUrl);
```