# REST services PATCH API example

Tags: java, json, rest

I am trying to call the REST Webservices PATCH API, here is My JSON payload

```
[
   { "op":"replace", "path":"/values/Timestamp","value":"2016-10-28T15:25:43.511Z"},
   { "op":"replace", "path":"/values/Flag",  "value":true },
   { "op":"replace", "path":"/values/Flow", "value":"Flow A"},
   {"op":"replace", "path":"/values/Interests", "value":[ "Sports", "Book Reading" ] }
]
```

JSON Value attribute has different values with different data types. and I want to prepare Entity object(Java) and convert it into JSON and call REST end point.
now
I am not very sure

> which is the best suitable data type I can choose for values attribute

I have referred following links but I didn't get enough details

[Android REST API using PATCH method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557953/android-rest-api-using-patch-method)
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2.1
http://blog.earaya.com/blog/2013/05/30/the-right-way-to-do-rest-updates/

http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/

but I didn't get enough details.

any suggestion on this is really appriciated

Comment: Why don't use `Object` as datatype for value! and based on the _field name_, cast it to required datatype

Comment: I want to use Gson or some other libraries to convert that Java object into JSON,  so during that phase, there will be an ambiguity.

Comment: You must __type cast__ it based on field type and then convert it to JSON using Gson.

But why do you need to convert it to JSON format again? Can you not just have __getter methods__ for object and use them to store values to DB

Comment: @Rohit I am developing client, and service expects JSON input, so I want to create a  Java object and set the data to that object and want to convert it into JSON string then pass it as payload

Comment: or is there any other alternative to do that ?

Comment: You need to work around a little and convert `Object` to _JSON_ format by yourself as you cannot stick to a specific data type each field has its own datatype. 
Else use String format for `value`, but, transform to proper format before setting the data in `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the java object from the client and created another Java class with below properties and set the values

1. opn - string
2. path - String
3. value - Object

added above java objects to array list then used the GSON library to convert it into the array of JSON objects which will be accepted by patch api.

and please note the content type is `application/json-patch+json`